# AngularJS : Fetching data from promise object in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I am working on module where I am submitting the form to the database and then getting response for the same, so when I return response from the servic[image]

[image]

I need to fetch the 'success' node value in data (which has true or false value).
Help would be appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using $http(), simply:

```
$http(params).success(function(resp){
   console.log(resp);
)}.error(function(err){
   console.log(err);
});
```

$http returns a $promise - using .success() or .then() waits for the promise to resolve, then executes inner code.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http for more info

Comment: Well I am following the same way, in the service I have following code

records.postdata = function(a,b){
   var params = {
    my_params:{
     details: b
    }
   }

  return $http.post($http)
   .success(function(data){
     console.log(data.success);
   })
   .error(function(error){
     alert(error);
   })
  }

then I am getting its result in controller in a variable, so I need to fetch value for success in controller itself

Comment: What is your console telling you? 

First off, you need to put the params in your $http.post, not $http. Secondly, be sure your params is formatted correctly to follow $http's documentation (link above). Your current params object will not work, as "my_params" is not a valid argument for $http. If it's a url parameter you're trying to add, it will be $http.post({params:{details: b}})

Comment: I am getting promise object in the console, I have attached the screen shot for the same in the question, I am able to post the data, but not able to reach 'data' node in the promise object

Comment: return $http.post(baseUrl + "/userid/" + userid + "/add_user", params)
   .success(function(data){
     console.log(data.success);
   })
   .error(function(error){
     alert(error);
   })
The code for posting is like this

Comment: if you are using return, then you need to just return the promise (so no success or errors). Use .then(function(result){}); after your service call in the controller. So, `SomeService.GetData().then()...`